# In Windows 2008R2 there is a TCP port that is stuck LISTENING but the process that has it open is terminated?

Tags: windows, tcp, process, zombie

I have a program, NC_net that allows Nagios to monitor Windows machines for various metrics and it seems to have caused a sporadic issue where when the service stops, the TCP port remains open.  The service has been stopped for over two hours and the port will not be released.

Any ideas on how to get this port to close without rebooting?  TCPview will allow you to click on the port and close it, but it does not work in this instance.

There is no local firewall that is running on this machine.

Tcpview:

```
<non-existent> 1552 TCP  EXPUBDR01-XXX 17   EXPUBDR01-XXX  0        LISTENING
```

Netstat:

```
c:\> netstat -ano|findstr 17
  TCP    0.0.0.0:17             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1552
  TCP    192.168.100.12:17       192.168.99.30:35028    CLOSE_WAIT      1552
  TCP    192.168.100.12:17       192.168.99.30:35029    CLOSE_WAIT      1552
  TCP    192.168.100.12:17       192.168.99.30:35030    CLOSE_WAIT      1552
  TCP    192.168.100.12:17       192.168.99.30:40994    ESTABLISHED     1552
  ...
  TCP    192.168.100.12:17       192.168.99.30:55207    CLOSE_WAIT      1552
  TCP    192.168.100.12:17       192.168.99.30:55208    CLOSE_WAIT      1552
  TCP    192.168.100.12:17       192.168.99.30:55210    CLOSE_WAIT      1552
```

Tasklist:

```
c:\> tasklist /fi "PID eq 1552"
INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.
```

Comment: is this process running under svchosts.exe

Comment: no sir.  according to process explorer, tasklist, task manager etc it is not running at all.